# Count number of values in array between two input values

Tags: javascript, arrays

As the title suggests, I want to create a function the counts the number of values in my array between two values that have been entered by the user. So for example, if the array was `[1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 6]` and the user entered `5` as their first value and `7` as their second value, they would be greeted with an alert that said

> "total number of values = 3".

Comment: OK. So where are you stuck? You forgot to ask a question. Simplest solution is probably a plain `for` loop containing an `if` statement... (Or if you want to get "fancy", you could use the array `.reduce()` method.)

Comment: Can array possibly contain numbers greater than `9`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extremely clean solution to this problem by utilizing the second property of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (which sets the `this` binding given to your callback of choice):

```js
var array = [1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 6]

function inRange (x) {
  return this[0] <= x && x <= this[1]
}

var result = array.filter(inRange, [5, 7]).length

console.log('Total number of values:', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a simple for loop.

```
var total = 0;
var num1 = 5;
var num2 = 7;
var array = [1,4,6,7,8,6];
for(var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    if(array[a] >= num1 && array[a] <= num2) {
         total++;
    }
}
alert("Total numbers of values = " + total);
```

This will loop through the array, detect nums within the range, tally up a value, and output it in a alert.

Comment: i just tried this, but no matter what I enter it keeps saying the total number of values is 0?

Comment: Working fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/wehw24L0/ What does your code look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()`, `RegExp.prototype.test()` with `RegExp` constructor with class `from-to`, where `from` is `5`, `to` is `7`, get `.length` of resulting array

```
var from = 5;
var to = 7;
var len = arr.filter(RegExp.prototype.test.bind(new RegExp(`[${from}-${to}]`))).length;
```

You can alternatively use `.toString()`, `.match()`

```js
var arr = [1,4,6,7,8,6];
var from = 5;
var to = 7;
var res = arr.toString().match(new RegExp(`[${from}-${to}]`, "g"));
var len = res.length;

console.log(res.length);
```

Comment: *"two values that have been entered by the user"* - What if the user enters `"5"` and `"17"`?

Comment: @nnnnnn Would need to adjust approach  `var len = arr.filter(n => n >= from && n <= to).length;`

Comment: `arr.filter(/./.test, RegExp(\`[${from}-${to}]\`, "g"))` is simpler

Comment: @dandavis Can you describe pattern? `RegExp` constructor is set to `this` within `.filter()`, yes? What is purpose for `/./`? Same as `RegExp.prototype`?

Comment: `/./.test` passes the generic `.test()` rx method, the 2nd argument tells that method what `this` is. simpler example: filter for even integers: `[0,1,2,3,4].filter(/./.test, /[02468]$/)` or find Capitals: `[].filter.call("Dan Davis", /./.test, /[A-Z]$/)`

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
var arr = [1,4,6,7,8,6],
  input = [5,7],
 result = arr.reduce((r,n) => n >= input[0] && n <= input[1] ? ++r : r, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 6];

function countNumber(arr,a,b){
    let count = 0;
    for (const number of arr){
        if (number >= a && number <= b){
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(countNumber(array, 5, 7));
```

Comment: you should also add an explanation to your code